# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android

I've only started android development, so forgive me if this question is a little basic. I've executed the following code in [Blue J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ) as well as [Android Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). Blue J doesn't seem to have any problem running it but Android Studio gives me this **"java.lang.NullPointerException"** error. I know what is supposed to cause this error, but there seem to be no calls to members of any *null* objects in my code:

```
public enum Seed {
    EMPTY,
    CROSS,
    NOUGHT
}

public class Cell {
    Seed content;

    Cell()
    {
        content = Seed.EMPTY;
    }
}

public class Board {
    Cell[][] cells;

    Board()
    {
        cells = new Cell[3][3];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                cells[i][j].content = Seed.EMPTY;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Board board;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        board = new Board();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know what kind of error is a NPE, why don't you give us only the relevant lines including the line where you get an NPE ?

Comment: the error occurs in the Board() constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cells = new Cell[3][3];
```

There you have a multidimensional array of null pointers.
You need to instantiate the contents of the array before using them:

```
Board()
{
    cells = new Cell[3][3];
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            cells[i][j] = new Cell()
            cells[i][j].content = Seed.EMPTY;
}
```